# Change file extensions and name at once using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory full of files output from some software as below:

- Pending.001
- Pending.002
- Pending.003
- etc.

I would like to use a .bat to rename them as below:

- Pending001.csv
- Pending002.csv
- Pending003.csv
- etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271107/bat-file-for-renaming-multiple-folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename your files in a loop, using the modifiers `~n` and `~x` on the loop variable to extract, respectively, the name and the extension of each file to concatenate them in the new name. As the extension would be extracted together with the leading `.`, you would also need a variable to temporarily store the extension before removing the `.`.

Here's an example of how the above could be implemented:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I IN (Pending.*) DO (
  SET "ext=%%~xI"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI!ext:~1!.csv"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

The delayed expansion is enabled because it is needed for the evaluation of `ext`. "Normal" expansion, which uses `%`, wouldn't work here because that way the variable would be expanded just once before the loop started, when the variable was still empty. In contrast, with the delayed expansion, the variable will be expanded every time the particular command containing it is executed, i.e. on every iteration of the loop too.

The above batch file would process files in the *current* directory, i.e. you would first need to change to the directory where the files need to be processed, then call the batch. Or, if you would be doing that in e.g. Windows Explorer, you would likely need to copy that batch to the directory with the files to process and call it from there.

Alternatively, though, you might want to call it with a parameter specifying the directory to process. To use the parameter, change the script like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I IN ("%~1\Pending.*") DO (
  SET "ext=%%~xI"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI!ext:~1!.csv"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Of course, you could also just specify a fixed path to the files if they are always in the same directory:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I IN ("D:\path\to\files\Pending.*") DO (
  SET "ext=%%~xI"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI!ext:~1!.csv"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

That way you would be able to call the batch from wherever you stored it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer to these posts:

1. [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)
2. [Bulk Rename Command](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Command.php)
3. [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/)
4. [Using batch files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true)