# CMD - Batch Rename multiple folder to one folder name with overwrite

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, directory

I would like to rename multiple folders to one folder name.

For Example batch file :

`G:
cd\TV Series
for /D %%f in (Game.of.Thrones.S01*) do rename "%%f" "Game of Thrones"`

The file requires a overwrite as the folder name "Game of Thrones" Already exist, is there a way to do a overwrite command?
see the following:

`for /D %%f in (Game.of.Thrones.S01E01.HDTV.x264-tvseries[xxx]*) do rename "%%f" "Game of Thrones"`

`for /D %%f in (Game.of.Thrones.S01E02.HDTV.x264-tvseries[xxx]*) do rename "%%f" "Game of Thrones"`

`for /D %%f in (Game.of.Thrones.S01E03.HDTV.x264-tvseries[xxx]*) do rename "%%f" "Game of Thrones"`

X amount of folders to 1 folder name.

In the batch file it should rename all folders to one folder. what do i do when the folder already exist how do i run a override "/y" on the master folder and also if the folder contains sub files & folders to allow the override?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.bat file for renaming multiple folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271107/bat-file-for-renaming-multiple-folders)

Comment: Hi Thank you, i have been sitting with that post for the past few hours and cant get it to work, That post only helps me to add a prefix onto current folders. The problem is what do i do when the folder already exist how do i run a override or "/y" on the master folder and also if the folder contains sub folders to allow the override?

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far in the questions, so people know that this isn't just a duplicate;  I unfortunately can't help you with that right now as I don't have a working Windows box right now.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if you need a batch file for this and am also not sure how flexible your desired solution is supposed to be, but in case it's only about this one example: You can do a windows search that will find all the files (maybe by searching for name and extension to exclude the folders). Then you can select all of those files and drag them into your desired folder.

After receiving comment: But there would be also an automated way. You could create a text file with one series name per row. Then you could loop over the file:

```
 FOR /F %%s IN ('type serieses.txt') DO (whatever)
```

Then in %%s there would be the name of the show. With that you can create a list of folder names for that show, where the wild card implies that there have to be more characters than only the show name:

```
 DIR %%s* > one_series.txt
```

Now you can loop that file as well, enter the directory copy everything and leave it again, which would roughly look like this:

```
PUSHD %%o
COPY *.mp3 %pathForAll%\%%s
POPD
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thank you i have more then 60 folder that needs to be renamed to a specific folder name every day. i need some kind of automation to rename the folders "SeriesNameS01E01xxx" to just "SeriesName" (This folder has existing content in the folder) and drop the "S01E01xxx" as there is files in the directory this will combine all the "mp4" files in one folder. If the sub folders and series file already exist there should be some kind of override.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found the answer.

It took me 2 Days finally!

`for /D %%f in (Game.of.Thrones.S*) do ROBOCOPY "%%f" "Game of Thrones" /MOVE`

Thanks everyone for the help