# How to rename folders keeping first 8 Characters and removing the rest

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have some folders which says `AA2017-123-TEXT` and `AA2017-124-TEXTS`.
I'm trying to use batch to rename these file to `AA2017-123` and `AA2017-124` removing the text from the folder name. That is I want only the first 8 characters in a folder name.
I am using windows 7

Comment: `AA2017-123` = 10 characters. How many characters do you want?

Comment: clear duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271107/bat-file-for-renaming-multiple-folders needs deletion

Comment: @MCND It is 10. I am asking generally. Thanks

Comment: @Drako The thread you mentioned talks about appending a text to the folder. I need to remove the text after a certain number of characters

Comment: @Ranjith, programming code is black and white.  There is no generalizations or ball park figures.  Speaking in generalizations will normally get you code that does not work.

Comment: please pay attention - shortening names can easily lead to duplicate names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what have been asked for, namely splitting off a certain amount of characters, the following code snippet could be used (extracting the first `10` characters here for example):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D "*"') do (
    set "FOLDER=%%D"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    move "!FOLDER!" "!FOLDER:~,10!"
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish your task, IMO the simplest is using the hyphens as delimiters in a for loop.

In the cmd line

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=-" %a in ('dir /B/ad *-*-*') do @echo ren "%a-%b-%c" "%a-%b"
```

In a batch

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B/ad *-*-*') do echo ren "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%%a-%%b"
```

If the output looks ok remove the echo